# How to install CouchDB on Mac OS X? (Docs not helping)

Tags: macos, curl, couchdb

I tried installing CouchDB 1.6 via Homebrew per the instructions on the official CouchDB docs at docs.couchdb.org, but I am having no success.  First, I tried the native application and that worked but apparently that version does not support CORS.  It has been a frustrating experience, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error that I am getting when trying to ping CouchDB:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5984: Connection refused
```

I followed the installation guide here: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/install/mac.html

These were the terminal commands I used:

```
open /Applications/Installers/Xcode\ Tools/XcodeTools.mpkg
--> File not found (this step is listed as optional, so I moved on)

brew update
brew doctor

brew install autoconf
brew install autoconf-archive
brew install automake
brew install libtool
brew install erlang
brew install icu4c
brew install spidermonkey
brew install curl

brew link icu4c
--> Requires --force option which can cause installations to fail
    (I did not do the --force option)
brew link erlang
brew install couchdb
--> To test CouchDB run: curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/

curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/
--> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5984: Connection refused
```

Mac Info:

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
OS X Yosemite
Version 10.10.3
```

Comment: My guess is that it is installed, but just not running. Can you try running `couchdb -d`? That should start it up in the background, if you need it to run on every startup, you can continue following the instructions for "Running as a Daemon".

Comment: That worked.  Thanks Dominic!  I assumed the install command had started the server since it suggested the curl command to test it.  I want to make sure that you get credit for answer, so I will accept it as soon as you add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that it is installed, but just not running. Can you try running `couchdb -d`?

That should start it up in the background, if you need it to run on every startup, you can continue following the instructions for "Running as a Daemon"

Comment: Thanks again!  I think the CouchDB docs should have a list of useful command-line commands.  The command you mentioned, couchdb -c (show paths to config files) and couchdb (start server) would be a great start.